# TypeError: _fakeTimers(...).LegacyFakeTimers is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

When running tests in a react-native Typscript based application i get a log full of the following errors:

```
FAIL  src/__test__/storeLayer.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _fakeTimers(...).LegacyFakeTimers is not a constructor

      at new NodeEnvironment (node_modules/jest-environment-node/build/index.js:123:23)
```

All able about it (and was solved) pointed to jest-environment-jsdom, but we not use it, and do not plan to use it, so any ideas where to look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue was the old dependency to

```
"@jest/fake-timers": "^26.0.1",
```

instead of the latest:

```
"@jest/fake-timers": "26.6.2",
```

I also updated babel jest:

```
"babel-jest": "26.6.3",
```

to match currently used jest version:

```
"jest": "26.6.3",
```

PS: a normal rebuild of course didn't serve, but after deleting node_modules and rebuilding, the error finally went away.